# Cross Thread call inside Console Application (close the console from another thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, console-application

I have a notifyIcon inside a thread, the icon have a contextMenu with a "Close" option, but I'm not able to close the console from there...

Using this code only closes the notifyIcon, not the console:

```
    public void mnuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notificationIcon.Dispose();
        notifyThread.Abort();
        timerThread.Abort();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I tried this, but there is no "Invoke" inside the console.

```
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate 
        {
            Application.Exit();
        });
```

### Edit

I'm using a thread to create a notifyIcon in the systemTray because thats the only way, there is nothing else.
The notifyIcon have a option called "Exit".
The Exit event method only closes the notifyIcon, but I want to close the Console window too.

Even if I just let the `Application.Exit();` inside the `mnuExit_Click`, only the notifyIcon closes.

My program.cs have this line of code to mantain the console open:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Maybe this is the problem... not sure. (but I need this)

Comment: Are you creating any form inside your app?

Comment: How do you open the console/form? (Application.Exit does what it says, so naturally the systray icon of your application will disappear when the application exits. What you really want is to close the form/console only, not your whole application - so you should keep some object reference to your console/form to be able to close it without exiting your app.)

Comment: Application.Exit() could only possibly do something to get the thread to exit, it isn't going to close a console window.  Environment.Exit() is the bigger hammer.

Comment: It's just a Console window with a notifyIcon with a contextMenu. Context menu item "exit" should close everything.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried just using `Environment.Exit(0);` but the same happens, just the icon desapears, but the Console still open.

Comment: That's going to require six cloves of garlic and a silver bullet.  Aim carefully.

Comment: Well, i'm gonna let this quiet for a while, the user can Always close in the X button.

Comment: Okay, my bad, I can't stop the Thread before calling Environment.Exti(0);

Facepalm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to define your own event. You can subscribe to it in the main thread and when it is fired you can close the app in your event handler